# FatSecret API - food.get method invalid signature

Tags: api, rest, platform

Hi 
 I am new to FatSecret Platform API and i developed a PHP script to 
 access food details using foods.search method 
 Here is the foods.search method Api call example,used Curl and works 
 perfect.

<?php 
 $consumer_key = "xxxxxxx"; 
 $secret_key = "xxxxxxx"; 
 //Signature Base String 
 //<HTTP Method>&<Request URL>&<Normalized Parameters> 
 $base = rawurlencode("GET")."&"; 
 $base .= "http%3A%2F%2Fplatform.fatsecret.com%2Frest%2Fserver. 
 api&";

//sort params by abc....necessary to build a correct unique signature 
 $params = "method=foods.search&"; 
 $params .= "oauth_consumer_key=$consumer_key&"; // ur consumer key 
 $params .= "oauth_nonce=123&"; 
 $params .= "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&"; 
 $params .= "oauth_timestamp=".time()."&"; 
 $params .= "oauth_version=1.0&"; 
 $params .= "search_expression=".urlencode($_GET['pasVar']); 
 $params2 = rawurlencode($params); 
 $base .= $params2;

//encrypt it! 
 $sig= base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base, "$secret_key&", 
 true)); // replace xxx with Consumer Secret

//now get the search results and write them down 
 $url = "http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api?". 
 $params."&oauth_signature=".rawurlencode($sig);

//$food_feed = file_get_contents($url); 
 list($output,$error,$info) = loadFoods($url); 
 echo '<pre>'; 
 if($error == 0){ 
     if($info['http_code'] == '200') 
         echo $output; 
     else 
         die('Status INFO : '.$info['http_code']);

} 
 
else 
     die('Status ERROR : '.$error);

function loadFoods($url) 
 {

// create curl resource 
         $ch = curl_init();

// set url 
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//return the transfer as a string 
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string 
         $output = curl_exec($ch);

$error = curl_error($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch); 
         // close curl resource to free up system resources 
         curl_close($ch);

return array($output,$error,$info);

} 
 
?>

the above script working perfect and retrieves food details using 
 search method.But

when i use food.get method to retrieve data using food_id it says 
 invalid signature error,Here's the food.get method api call example,I 
 have given correct keys and passed food_id parameter.Can someone help 
 me to solve the issue,I am really struck on this code.It says invalid 
 signature error.

<?php 
 $consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxx"; 
 $secret_key = "xxxxxxxxxx"; 
 //Signature Base String 
 //<HTTP Method>&<Request URL>&<Normalized Parameters> 
 $base = rawurlencode("GET")."&"; 
 $base .= "http%3A%2F%2Fplatform.fatsecret.com%2Frest%2Fserver.api&";

//sort params by abc....necessary to build a correct unique signature 
 $params = "method=food.get&"; 
 $params .= "oauth_consumer_key=$consumer_key&"; // ur consumer key 
 $params .= "oauth_nonce=".rand()."&"; 
 $params .= "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&"; 
 $params .= "oauth_timestamp=".time()."&"; 
 $params .= "oauth_version=1.0&"; 
 $params .= "food_id=".urlencode($_GET['pasVar']); 
 $params2 = rawurlencode($params); 
 $base .= $params2;

//encrypt it! 
 $sig= base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base, "$secret_key&", 
 true)); // replace xxx with Consumer Secret

//now get the search results and write them down 
 $url = "http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api?". 
 $params."&oauth_signature=".rawurlencode($sig);

//$food_feed = file_get_contents($url); 
 list($output,$error,$info) = loadFoods($url); 
 echo '<pre>'; 
 if($error == 0){ 
     if($info['http_code'] == '200') 
         echo $output; 
     else 
         die('Status INFO : '.$info['http_code']);

} 
 
else 
     die('Status ERROR : '.$error);

function loadFoods($url) 
 {

// create curl resource 
         $ch = curl_init();

// set url 
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//return the transfer as a string 
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string 
         $output = curl_exec($ch);

$error = curl_error($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch); 
         // close curl resource to free up system resources 
         curl_close($ch);

return array($output,$error,$info);

} 
 
?>

Help me what's the error in the code and help me to solve the issue as 
 i have to use this API in my project

Thanks waiting for your replies....

Comment: I have used your above code but facing the auth signature issue using foods.serach method

Answer (score 3):

You should order you params by alpha.
So you should do it in this order:

```
$params = "food_id=".urlencode($_GET['pasVar'])."&"; 
$params .= "method=food.get&";
$params .= "oauth_consumer_key=$consumer_key&"; // ur consumer key
$params .= "oauth_nonce=".rand()."&";
$params .= "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&";
$params .= "oauth_timestamp=".time()."&";
$params .= "oauth_version=1.0";
```